# How to write a SQL query with minimum and maximum salary from each department by date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table like below:

```
 dept  | salary | year
 ------+--------+-----
 HR    | 1000   | 2014
 Acc   | 2000   | 2014
 Acc   | 1000   | 2015
 Acc   | 3000   | 2015
 Dev   | 5000   | 2015
```

I want to find the department having minimum and maximum salary which is grouped by a year. The expected output is as follows:

```
year | min_sal_dept | max_sal_dept
-----+--------------+-----
2014     HR             Acc
2015     Acc            Dev
```

How can I write a SQL query for getting output in such a way?

Comment: which query did you try and what was the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select year,
       max(dept) filter (where seqnum_asc = 1) as min_salary_dept,
       max(dept) filter (where seqnum_desc = 1) as max_salary_dept
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year order by salary) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by year order by salary desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
group by year;
```

If you don't want subqueries, you can use arrays:

```
select year,
       (array_agg(dept order by salary asc))[1] as min_salary_dept,
       (array_agg(dept order by salary desc))[1] as max_salary_dept
from t
group by year;
```